# Cycles Render Output Black

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

So my problem is simple: My render output is black.
I have rendered correctly before but now fear that I have accidentally changed a setting. I can't seem to figure out what it is...

My file is on [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0SOwCTySdtAOFRabU43OFhld3M); hope that's okay.

Thanks guys.

Comment: Please post your file [here](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com) for BSE questions.

Comment: Apologies. Will do next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the *Properties panel > Render Layers tab > Layer dropdown* and erase *BoneMaterial* as your *Material:*

[image]

From the [Wiki](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/post_process/layers.html) (regarding **Material Override**):

> Overrides all material settings to use the Material chosen here.
>
> Examples of where this might be used:
>
> - To check lighting by using a plain diffuse material on all objects
> - Render a wireframe of the scene
> - Create a custom render pass such as an anti-aliased matte or global coordinates.

You had inadvertently changed every material in the scene to one that did not render correctly.

**EDIT:**

Newer versions of blender don't use layers, but "collections" so the override function is in the scene>View Layer section.

[image]

Additional info:

[Where is the Layers panel in Blender 2.8?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/96463/where-is-the-layers-panel-in-blender-2-8/96465#96465)

[2.8 - Is it possible to assign (override) a material to a whole collection?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/136678/2-8-is-it-possible-to-assign-override-a-material-to-a-whole-collection)

Comment: Thank you so much. I was looking for close to two hours. :)

Comment: May I suggest adding a few words as to why the material override caused the problem? May prove helpful to someone else in the future.

Comment: @Tim Glad to help!

Comment: @Timaroberts Does this help?